# Simulate block finalization error

Tags: testing, parachain-collator, test-network, finalization

I would like to simulate how our parachain reacts to events like,

1. A collator produces a block that is not accepted by other collators in that parachain. Aka a malicious collator.
2. The relay chain rejects A block produced in the parachain.

Do you have any way to reach those stages? First ( on my limited knowledge ) I think it can be done by a collator that differs somehow on the runtime with others, but second, I don't know how to do it.

Any tips here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use zombienet tests. For example, take a look at this test:

- https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet/blob/main/tests/dispute-valid-block.test.js

You would want to have a zombienet test to generate a "bad" collation and trigger a dispute.

Comment: interesting, will look at it! thanks :)